# Does JS support sorting with a key function, rather than a comparator?

Tags: javascript, sorting

JavaScript's [`array.sort`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/sort#Syntax) method takes an optional compare function as argument, which takes two arguments and decides which one of them is smaller than the other.

However, sometimes it would be more convenient to customize the sort order with a *key function*, which is a function that takes *one* value as an argument and assigns it a *sort key*. For example:

```
function keyFunc(value){
    return Math.abs(value);
}

myArr = [1, 3, -2];
myArr.sort(keyFunc);
// the result should be [1, -2, 3]
```

Does JavaScript have support for this, or is there no way around writing a full-blown comparison function?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There's no support for *exactly* what you describe, but it's quite trivial to write a standard `.sort` function that achieves the same thing, with minimal code - just return the *difference* between calling `keyFunc` on the two arguments to `sort`:

```js
function keyFunc(value){
    // complicated custom logic here, if desired
    return Math.abs(value);
}

myArr = [1, 3, -2];
myArr.sort((a, b) => keyFunc(a) - keyFunc(b));
console.log(myArr);
// the result should be [1, -2, 3]
```

If the key function is complicated and you don't want to run it more than necessary, then it would be pretty simple to create a lookup table for each input, accessing the lookup table if `keyFunc` has been called with that value before:

```js
const keyValues = new Map();
function keyFunc(value){
    const previous = keyValues.get(value);
    if (previous !== undefined) return previous
    console.log('running expensive operations for ' + value);
    // complicated custom logic here, if desired
    const result = Math.abs(value);
    keyValues.set(value, result);
    return result;
}

myArr = [1, 3, -2];
myArr.sort((a, b) => keyFunc(a) - keyFunc(b));
console.log(myArr);
// the result should be [1, -2, 3]
```

Comment: I'm going a bit out of scope of the question here, but in my specific use case the key function is rather expensive to execute. That's why I'd like to avoid calling it twice for each pair of values that needs to be compared. Could you possibly expand your answer to cover that use case, or should I post a new question specifically about sorting with an expensive comparison function?

Comment: @aran-fey I'd say that this would be a new question

Comment: ... which won't work for objects, I'd rather use a `Map` here.

Answer (score 1):

As stated already you have to write that functionality yourself or extend the current array `sort` method etc.

Another approach is if you ware using `lodash` and its [**orderBy**](https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.10#orderBy) method ... then this becomes:

```js
myArr=[1, 3, -2];

const result = _.orderBy(myArr, Math.abs)

console.log(result)
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/lodash.js/4.17.11/lodash.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can easily subtract the "keys" from the two elements:

```
 myArr.sort((a, b) => keyFunc(a) - keyFunc(b));
```

You could also monkey patch `sort`:

```
 {
   const { sort } = Array.prototype;
   Array.prototype.sort = function(sorter) {
    if(sorter.length === 2) {
      sort.call(this, sorter);
    } else {
       sort.call(this, (a, b) => sorter(a) - sorter(b));
    }
  };
}
```

So then:

```
 myArr.sort(keyFunc);
```

works.

Comment: I don't use JS much, so I'm not sure about common practices there, but monkey-patching `Array.sort` seems kind of... ugly, and also risky. Won't that break anything...?

Answer (score 0):

You could use a closure over the wanted function.

```js
const
    keyFunc = value => Math.abs(value),
    sortBy = fn => (a, b) => fn(a) - fn(b),
    array = [1, 3, -2];

array.sort(sortBy(keyFunc));
console.log(array); // [1, -2, 3]
```