# How can I efficiently sort an array based on a computationally expensive key function?

Tags: javascript, sorting

I asked [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/52683537/1222951) about sorting an array with a key function, where it turned out that there is no way to avoid using a comparison function.

The problem is that

1. I have a computationally expensive *key* function, which I somehow have to turn into a *comparison* function
2. I'm sorting an array of objects, which means I can't use a hash table to memoize the results of my key function

Here's a sample array and (cheap) key function:

```
myArr = [{'foo': 5, 'bar': 'hello'}, {'foo': 3, 'bar': 'world'}];
keyFunc = obj => obj.foo;  // sort by the value of the `foo` attribute

myArr.sort(???);
// result should be [{'foo': 3, 'bar': 'world'}, {'foo': 5, 'bar': 'hello'}]
```

Given these circumstances, how can I *efficiently* sort my array?

Comment: A `Map` as in the prior answer can indeed cache results for objects, does it not work for you?

Comment: How do you define 'efficiently'?

Comment: @NikolaDimitroff The key function should be executed only once per array element.

Comment: @CertainPerformance I can certainly make a working solution with `Map`, but I'm not sure how efficient that is - do they have O(1) lookup time? Anyway I think there are better solutions available, one of which I will post shortly.

Comment: Yes, `Map`s have guaranteed `O(1)` lookup time.

Comment: Given an object `obj` from your list. Will `key(obj)` ever return two different values depending on when it is called?

Comment: @Code-Apprentice No, it'll always return the same value. But the key function should ideally only be called once for each object anyway.

Comment: C'mon people, we need some more answers down there! I know it's late at night, but where's everyone's competitive spirit?

Comment: @CertainPerformance Conceptually, that's true. I'm not sure that holds in practice in all implementations of ES.

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Schwartzian_transform

Answer (score 0):

Since we want to run the expensive key function only once per array element, we have no choice but to use some sort of memoization. The easiest way to associate a key value with each element is probably to create an array of `[key, element]` pairs, which we can then sort:

```
myArr = [{'foo': 5, 'bar': 'hello'}, {'foo': 3, 'bar': 'world'}];
keyFunc = obj => obj.foo;

// compute the key of each array element
keyedArr = myArr.map(obj => [keyFunc(obj), obj]);

// sort the array based on the key
keyedArr.sort((a, b) => a[0] - b[0])

// remove the key values from the array
result = keyedArr.map(pair => pair[1]);
// result: [{'foo': 3, 'bar': 'world'}, {'foo': 5, 'bar': 'hello'}]
```

Note that this only works if the key function returns a number.